# TypeError: unbound method get_pet() must be called with DogFactory instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python

I am going to learn Abstract Factory Pattern And write some code for test.

There is a DogFactory and a CatFactory, I want to use a PetFactory to return a pet.

But get a error 
TypeError: unbound method get_pet() must be called with DogFactory instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
The script is:

```
import random

class PetShop(object):
    """A Pet Shop"""
    def __init__(self, animal_factory=None):
        self.pet_factory = animal_factory

    def get_pet(self):
        return self.pet_factory.get_pet()

    def get_food(self):
        return self.pet_factory.get_food()


class Dog(object):
    def speak(self):
        return "woof"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Dog"

class Cat(object):
    def speak(self):
        return "meow"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Cat"


class DogFactory(object):
    """Create a Dog"""
    def get_pet(self):
        return Dog()

    def get_food(self):
        return "dog food"

class CatFactory(object):
    """Create a Cat"""
    def get_pet(self):
        return Cat()

    def get_food(self):
        return "Cat food"

def main():
    factory = random.choice([DogFactory, CatFactory])
    petshop = PetShop(factory)
    print petshop.get_pet()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I searched some similar question but got no idea, If you could explain to me, that would be great.

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to instantiate your factory:

```
def main():
    FactoryCls = random.choice([DogFactory, CatFactory])
    petshop = PetShop(FactoryCls())
    print petshop.get_pet()
```

This results in `self.pet_factory.get_pet()` in `PetShop` failing when it calls `get_pet()` on the factory **class**.

This fails because `get_pet` is a method, which you're supposed to call "from" an **instance**:

```
DogFactory().get_pet()  # Good
DogFactory.get_pet()    # Bad
```

---

Alternatively, you could make `get_pet` a `classmethod` on your factory class.

Comment: Thank you!  I have got it.                                          factory = random.choice([DogFactory, CatFactory])() also works. best wishes!